# Including literal HTML code in org-mode templates

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

In org-mode, when you export HTML projects you can use templates to give all exported pages the same options, this is described here http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html. What I would like to do, is give all exported pages an HTML snippet, for analytics, which is not an option. Is this possible with org-templates?

Now, I tried to add literal HTML code to the base template `level-0-template.org` with

```
#begin_html
...
#end_html
```

but it didn't work out. Does anyone know how to add html code to each HTML file that is exported in the project?

My project is organized as follows:

```
|- org
   |- index.org
|- html
   |- index.html (this is exported)
|- templates
   |- level-0.org (I'd like to include default html here)
|- org_publish.el (this is the publishing config file)
```

Comment: Where are you trying to include the literal HTML code?  A more complete example of your setup would make it easier to see what is needed.

Comment: Are you including `level-0.org` using `#+setupfile: <path>/level-0.org`?  If you are try changing that to `#+include: <path>/level-0.org`.  (If that does what you want I'll provide as an answer with more details)

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin This worked, although I placed the html snippet in a separate file that is included in all other org files. I don't know the difference between `#+setupfile` and `#+include`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my comment in the question, here is the difference between `#+setupfile:` and `#+include:`.

Details about both are available in the Org-Mode manual.  See [Setup File](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html) and [Include Files](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html).

The setupfile is essentially a list of all org configurations that are included in the linked file.  It will pass things such as `#+options`.  It will not however include any other content that the original file might include.

On the other hand, `#+include:` inserts the content of the linked file wherever the line is inserted.  It acts similarly to `\input` in LaTex.  I'm not certain to what degree it will bring along any org-configuration settings from the linked file, you may need to both `#+include` and `#+setupfile` the file to ensure everything is present.  However since you do want the body content of the file to be included in each, you have to use `#+include` to insert it.

Answer (score 3):

Glad you found a solution to your problem by sourcing your snippet as a separate html file.

If you wanted to make it work by having the snippet directly included in your template file, you should use:

```
#+BEGIN_export html
...
#+END_export
```

instead of:

```
#+BEGIN_html
...
#+END_html
```

(The latter will embed the html chunk as a block in the rendered html page-not what you want; the former will export the html chunk as is in the html file so that that code will be rendered when the page is displayed-what you want).